# Update version of network manager

Tags: linux, centos, command-line-interface, linux-networking, shell

In shell on sever I see following error after launching several commands:

`Error: nmcli (1.0.0) and NetworkManager (0.9.9.1) versions don't match. Force execution using --nocheck, but the results are unpredictable`

I've found that there are newer versions of NetworkManager. How can I update it?

I've tried `yum update NetworkManager` with no success

I use `CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)`

Comment: What operating system and version are you using?

Comment: @I use `CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)`

Comment: what errors do you get when you run `yum update NetworkManager`

Comment: @Ankh2054, I'm getting no errors, just `... No packages marked for update`

Comment: Who installed this system?

Answer (score 4):

I was running into the same issue. Apparently even though NetworkManager had been updated, the version that was still loaded in memory and running was older. Try restarting the service:

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

to verify it works test the following command:

```
sudo nmcli -p g
```

You should see the NetworkManager status, instead of the pesky "versions don't match" error.